# How to extract multiple searches with regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string from which I want to extract certain words and I have used Python's regular expression but unfortunately I am only getting one word from all the matches.

Here is my input string

```
go = "GO:0030054^cellular_component^cell junction`GO:0005813^cellular_component^centrosome`GO:0036064^cellular_component^ciliary basal body`GO:0005737^cellular_component^cytoplasm"
```

Here is my regular expression I tried

```
go_search = re.search(r'(GO:\d+)', go, re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

But the only output I got is

```
go_search.group(1)
'GO:0030054'
```

How can I get all the 4 GO'id's (GO:0005813, GO:0036064, and GO:0005737) and not just one which I am just getting now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) instead of `re.search`:

```
re.findall(r'GO:\d+', go, re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)
# ['GO:0030054', 'GO:0005813', 'GO:0036064', 'GO:0005737']
```

Comment: That was fast and it worked as I want it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace `re.search()` with `re.finditer()`. This gives you an iterator over the matches.

```
go = "GO:0030054^cellular_component^cell junction`GO:0005813^cellular_component^centrosome`GO:0036064^cellular_component^ciliary basal body`GO:0005737^cellular_component^cytoplasm"
go_search_iter = re.finditer(r'(GO:\d+)', go, re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)

for go_search in go_search_iter:
    print(go_search.group(1))
    # do stuff with go_search
```